# Reproduce orthogonal images from 2d consecutive image set

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing, image3d

I have 3474 images (png, 8bit, gey scale, horizontal size x=3107 pixels, vertical size y=1200 pixels).

The images can be downloaded here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rK7xlbFIGMG4O3Z-w82cgqQQTJwEbVvU

They are obtained from a depth scan in the perpendicular z direction.

**I want to reproduce from all x-y images the corresponding x-z images.**

---

I thought first to read in all images via `Image3D`.

To read in the images I used:

```
fNames = FileNames["*.png"];
numFiles = Length[fNames]; (* = 3747 *)
readImage[ index_] := Import[fNames[[index]]]; 
AbsoluteTiming[image3d=Image3D[Table[readImage[i],{i,numFiles}]];]
{201.538,Null}
```

So the waiting time is not so critical.

But I have no idea how to access image slices in the x-z direction?

Do you know if `Image3D` can be used for my problem?

---

If `Image3D` cannot be used I thought I could try the following:

```
imagesArray3d=Array[0&, {3747, 1200, 3107}];

Do[
   imagesArray3d[[i]] = ImageData[Import[fNames[[i]],"PNG"]];
   ,{i, 3747}
];
```

To access a single x-z image e.g. at y=600 I could use:

```
Image[imagesArray3d[[All, 600, All]]]
```

The main problem here is I cannot allocate enough memory:

```
imagesArray3d=Array[0&, {3747, 1200, 3107}];
```

gives me:

```
General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.
Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[…, _SystemException].
```

**Do you know a solution how to extract the x-z images.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is not very fast, but the RAM usage is low:

```
zMax = 3474;
data = "C:\\ims\\all.dat";
files = FileNames["C:\\ims\\*.png"][[;; zMax]];

Quiet[Close[data]; Close[str]];
str = BinaryWrite[data, {}];

Dynamic[track]
MapIndexed[(track = #2; BinaryWrite[str, ImageData[Import[#], "Byte"]]) &, files];
Close[str];

str = OpenRead[data, BinaryFormat -> True];
Do[Export["c:\\ims\\xz\\" <> ToString[y] <> ".png",
  Image[Table[track = y; SetStreamPosition[str, 3107*(y - 1) + 3107*1200*(z - 1)];
    BinaryReadList[str, "Byte", 3107], {z, zMax}], "Byte"]], {y, 1200}];
Close[str];
```

Comment: This is great and I have never seen something similar which uses such a small amount of RAM. Your `MapIndexed` part takes on my computer 276 sec. So if I compare that with my solution, the total time is similar … BUT YOUR CODE can handle many more images. Great! Can you please insert some comments between the code what your idea was. I am not experienced how you work with the files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which uses rotation of the 3d image and then allows with `Image3DSlices` to get the orhogonal images:

```
fNames = FileNames["*.png"];

numFiles = Length[fNames]; (* = 3747 *)

readImage[ index_] := Import[fNames[[index]]]; 

image3d = 
   Image3D[Table[readImage[i], {i, numFiles}]]; // AbsoluteTiming

{189.654, Null}

image3dXZ = ImageRotate[image3d, {Pi/2, {1, 0, 0}}]; // AbsoluteTiming

{67.4332, Null}

ImageAdjust[Image3DSlices[image3dXZ, 600], {0, 5}] ( * cut throught y = 600* )
```

[image]